# send data with jquery.load()

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, jquery-load

how do I send some data to the server in the .load() function of jquery. I tried this syntax:

```
$('container').load('path', {key: value});
```

but for some reason it doesn't work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is *never* a good error description. Please describe what goes wrong, what error messages you get, etc. Also, there is a [manual](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Try posting the code you are using, else its impossible for us to help.

Answer (score 30):

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load) uses POST or GET depending on the parameter passed.

If it's an object, it uses POST:

```
$('container').load('path', {key: value});
```

Otherwise, it uses GET:

```
$('container').load('path', 'key=value');
```

Without any other info in your question, this is all I could come up with to help.